# IMBNDeviceService interface of Mobile broadband API

Tags: mobile-broadband-api

Can we send AT commands by using Microsoft Mobile Broadband APIs in Windows 8 laptop? I know there is SetCommand() method in IMBNDeviceService interface. Can we send AT commands through it? If so, what is the syntax. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't.  The DeviceServices interfaces are for sending MBIM interface commands, defined [here.](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCQQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.usb.org%2Fpress%2FUSB-IF_Press_Releases%2FUSB_MBIM_Spec_Release_Final.pdf&ei=HEX4VN__Jo7fPfrYgOgN&usg=AFQjCNFLeuXoJb1N4BwNH4YADiNifyDUnQ)  You can use the Mobile Broadband API DeviceServices interfaces to see which MBIM interfaces are exposed by your device, defined by their GUIDs.
The MBIM interfaces have their own commands, hence the SetCommand() method.

If you want to send AT commands, find the device's COM port, and use that instead.  Not all modern devices expose a COM port.

Comment: How do I find out the COM port used by my SIM card on laptop? Is there any specific driver I need to install? In DeviceManager I do not find any modems category. However the Sierra Skylight software detects my SIM card.

Comment: If you can't see a COM port in Windows Device Manager, then maybe the device does not expose one.  Maybe the Sierra software uses the network adapter instead.  You would have to ask the laptop manufacturer about a different driver.